# How to go about creating a SQL Server Agent clone / customization (NOT another SQL Server Express Agent question)

Tags: sql-server, components, agent

I'm managing a web app featuring countless ETL (Extract, Transform & Load) processes feeding a datawarehouse (using SSIS dtsx packages + *.sql files).

At the moment, everything is governed by several SQL Agent processes monitoring "scheduling queue" tables.

I'm trying to figure out a way to develop a scheduler or scheduling "framework" of some sort that needs to do a subset of what SQL Server Agent does (executing dtsx packages, executing SQL) but with a configuration UI based on ASP.NET, as users need to be able to create & modify schedules, manually launch processes and monitor custom logs.

Configuration info, activity, execution logs, schedules, jobs, job steps and everything else needed that I'm missing should be persisted to DB.

I'm guessing a Windows Service would be flexible but development costs might skyrocket.

I appreciate any sort of input, particularly some clues on SQL Server Agent's internal workflow. I DID try searching for info, but it being PROPRIETARY software, I found zilch.

(maybe I should specify I'm more than familiar with SQL Server and C# based .NET development, I just have no idea where to start from..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist of the answer is one should use SQL Server Service Broker, coupled with SQL Server Service Broker External Activator from the Feature Pack

Answer (score 0):

The SQL server agent database is called 'msdb'.  You can attach profiler to msdb and create some scheduled jobs to see how it works.